# How can I listen to service-topics?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

When debugging actions, I often do a **rostopic echo** on the goal and result topic. However, I haven't found similar
topics for services. How can I listen to this communication?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214787/how-can-i-listen-to-service-topics?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-29**:
Have you tried rosservice command?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
With rosservice you can not get into the communication, you can just call a existing service

```
rosservice options -> call  find  list  type  uri
```

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-29**:
I rarley use rosservice, that is why I wasn't sure :)

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-29**:
Me too, actually when you have something wrong, everything can hang :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Services are not topics. I guess there is no way to look into it, there is only one service with the same name allowed.
Because services are blocking calls, like function calls.
So to listen to a service, you must provide it, but I guess there is no way to "listen" to it if you are not the call receiver.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-29**:
ok, thanks. I guess I just have to use actions.